# SELECT DEPENDIENTE PHP

Tags: php, mysql

espero me puedan apoyar con esto: Lo que deseo es obtener el id del colegio que fue seleccionado en el SELECT y luego dependiendo de eso, jalarlo en un variable y colocarlo en mi CONSULTA SQL, para que dpendendiendo de lo que ponga aparezca el grado y seccion que fue registrado en ese colegio.

```
          <div class="form-group">
            <label class="col-sm-2 control-label">Colegio</label>
            <div class="col-sm-5">
              <select class="chosen-select" name="cole_id" autocomplete="off" required>
                <option value="">Selecciona un Colegio</option>
                <?php  foreach ($all_colegios as $cole): ?>
                  <option value="<?php echo (int)$cole['cole_id'] ?>">
                    <?php echo $cole['cole_nombre']?></option>
                <?php endforeach; ?>
              </select>
            </div>
          </div>

          <div class="form-group">
            <label class="col-sm-2 control-label">Salon</label>
            <div class="col-sm-5">
              <select class="chosen-select" name="sal_id" autocomplete="off" required>
              <option value="">Selecciona un Salon</option>
               <?php  
               $all_salones = mysqli_query($mysqli,  "SELECT * FROM salones WHERE cole_id = 1");
               foreach ($all_salones as $sal): ?>
                  <option value="<?php echo (int)$sal['sal_id'] ?>">
                    <?php echo $sal['sal_grado'] . " " . $sal['sal_seccion']?></option>
                <?php endforeach; ?>
              </select>
            </div>
          </div>
```

Comment: ¿Y cuál es el problema en sí Cristhian?

Comment: Deseo obtener el value del codigo colegio y en mi consulta:
 $all_salones = mysqli_query($mysqli,  "SELECT * FROM salones WHERE cole_id = -->1<--") no poner uno si no el value del codigo del colegio;

Comment: Entendido, quizá convendría que pongas esa información en la pregunta y que digas cómo tienes montado el programa. Lo mejor en esto sería usar Ajax para enviar el dato por Ajax al servidor y que la página no tenga que recargarse cada vez para ir a buscar datos al servidor. ¿Cómo tienes montado el programa?

Answer (score 0):

Debes meter ese código que tienes de html dentro de un formulario y ponerle un botón así:

```
     //formulario
     <form class="" action="accion.php" method="post">
      //formulario
       <div class="form-group">
        <label class="col-sm-2 control-label">Colegio</label>
        <div class="col-sm-5">
          <select class="chosen-select" name="cole_id" autocomplete="off" required>
            <option value="">Selecciona un Colegio</option>
            <?php  foreach ($all_colegios as $cole): ?>
              <option value="<?php echo (int)$cole['cole_id'] ?>">
                <?php echo $cole['cole_nombre']?></option>
            <?php endforeach; ?>
          </select>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="form-group">
        <label class="col-sm-2 control-label">Salon</label>
        <div class="col-sm-5">
          <select class="chosen-select" name="sal_id" autocomplete="off" required>
          <option value="">Selecciona un Salon</option>
           <?php  
           $all_salones = mysqli_query($mysqli,  "SELECT * FROM salones WHERE cole_id = 1");
           foreach ($all_salones as $sal): ?>
              <option value="<?php echo (int)$sal['sal_id'] ?>">
                <?php echo $sal['sal_grado'] . " " . $sal['sal_seccion']?></option>
            <?php endforeach; ?>
          </select></br>
          //boton
         <input type="button" name="" value="Seleccionar">
          //boton
        </div>
      </div> 
   </form>
```

Luego crear un archivo que tenga la extension .php por ejemplo crearemos el archivo "accion.php" el nombre de este archivo debe de ir en el action del formulario así como te mostré arriba

Luego para recibir los datos debes poner el siguiente código en el archivo php

```
<?php

  $colegio = $_POST["col_id"];
  $salon = $_POST["sal_id"];

  echo $colegio;
  echo $salon;

?>
```

Ya con esto traes el id del colegio y del salón y puedes hacer tu consulta según el salón o colegio seleccionado